# How can I change the SQL Server Expess instance name / path

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a working SQL Server Express running in my computer as `MYPC\SQLEXPRESS`.

In my ASP.NET MVC 5 project I need to use this connection string in order to connect with it:

```
<add name="maymoneyDB" 
     connectionString="Server=MYPC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=myDB;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

The problem is that my coworkers have their SQL Server instances at `.` so I need to change the connection string each time I pull changes from TFS.

How can I change my server path? I try with [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143799.aspx) but seems to change `@@SERVERNAME` but not the path.

Any explanation about handle this situation is also helpful (maybe change the path is not the best approach).

Thanks

Comment: You could remove and re-install SQL Server and install it as the **default** (unnamed) instance on your machine - after that, you'd be able to connect to it using `.` also

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing SQL Server named instance to default instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7831137/changing-sql-server-named-instance-to-default-instance)

Comment: did you tried using `IP address` ??

Comment: either you can connect your coworker DB or you have to change each time your connection instance in web config. another way don't take update of web.config from TFS